# VictoryChart: dynamic width dependent on axis label width

Tags: javascript, react-native, charts, victory-charts

I'm using victory-native in React-Native and can't figure this one out.

I'm creating a VictoryCandlestick with two axis so I have something like this:

[image]

Problem I have now is that my data is dynamic, the numbers on the right can go into millions. Is there a way to calculate how much offset I should give to my axis based on the width of the axis/labels? Otherwise, my text is cut-off on the right side of the screen, or overlaps the graph if I change the VictoryLabel textAnchor

Answer (score 1):

The cut-off text you can solve with the padding property, like for example:
`padding={{ top: 40, bottom: 80, left: 40, right: 80 }}`

You can se on the documentation: https://formidable.com/open-source/victory/docs/common-props/#padding

Regarding the quantity of data in the axis, due the the data being dynamic, you can solve by adding a "zoom" container, like for example `containerComponent={<VictoryZoomContainer zoomDomain={{ y: [ 0.0080, 0.0120 ] }} />}`, where you can set an interval to be the initial range to be shown on one or both axis, and the user will the able to pan through the axis you define. Here is the link to the documentation: https://formidable.com/open-source/victory/docs/victory-zoom-container/

Another option would be implementing something like this example here https://formidable.com/open-source/victory/gallery/brush-zoom/